# Selenium test scripts to login into google account through new ajax login form

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to write scripts to give my email address into email element. But once click next through scripts Google uses ajax to replace that email element to password element dynamically. This is where I am stuck and won't be able to give password in that element and no login.

URL: https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin

Please write the selenium test scripts to achieve this.

Comment: Which Selenium Binding are you using? Selenium through Java/Python/C#/JavaScript/Ruby/Perl ? Can we see your code block?

Comment: share you code you have tried

Comment: Selenium through Java

Comment: I don't require whole bunch of code only the driver send keys to password then login button click. Which will make successful login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code block to access the url `https://accounts.google.com/signin` login with your valid credentials and print the `Page Title` on your console:

```
String url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin";
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
WebElement email_phone = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"));
email_phone.sendKeys("your_email");
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password));
password.sendKeys("your_password");
driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click(); 
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

Console Output:

```
Google Accounts
```

---

### Update(5-Jan-2020)

Optimizing the above code block and adding a couple of arguments you can use:

```
public class browserAppDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"))).sendKeys("emailID");
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"))).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any update on this? It says that my webbrowser is insecure after entering the password and clicking next.