# how to switch the control from 1 chrome browser to another using selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium

I m using the https://www.myntra.com/ website for Automating using selenium with java.
Once i click on login it shows me option login using Facebook and Google after i  click on Sign in with google. how do i take control of the Google sign page using selenium(how to switch control to google sign in window from https://www.myntra.com window using selenium) they are in  the same  browser

Comment: I have added an answer for that. Please let me know your results

Comment: For reference you can also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572527/how-to-control-the-newly-opened-window-that-appears-after-a-click-in-selenium-we/47572795#47572795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String parentHandle = browser.getWindowHandle();
browser.findElement( By.cssSelector(".desktop-userIconsContainer") ).click();
browser.findElement( By.linkText("LOGIN") ).click();
browser.findElement( By.id("gPlusLogin") ).click();

for (String googleHandle : browser.getWindowHandles() ){
        browser.switchTo().window(googleHandle);
}

new WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable( By.id( "identifierId" ) )).sendKeys("yoyo");
browser.switchTo().window(parentHandle);  // use this for switching back to parent window
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation as to how and why your code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To switch the control to new window using selenium the implementation is below

```
 String mainWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();

    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
```

Please let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Once you `click()` on the link **`GOOGLE`** a new `Window` is opened. So you have to change the `Window` through `WindowHandles` as follows :

```
String first_win = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_xpath")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> i1 = s1.iterator();
while(i1.hasNext())
{
    String next_win = i1.next();
    if (!first_win.equalsIgnoreCase(next_win))
    {
    driver.switchTo().window(next_win);

    System.out.println("Working on Sign In Window");
    }
}
```