# Google search locate elements not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
  String baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=SiwuWq0Rx5xfj9ug2Aw";
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Geco\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get(baseUrl);
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  //driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("test");
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Trying to search google search button with selenium web driver but it's not working.

Comment: you are setting capabilities for chrome but you are using geckdriver?

Comment: @MahmudRiad Need to edit it i m using firefox driver.

Comment: Check out [**Selenium test scripts to login into google account through new ajax login form**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953043/selenium-test-scripts-to-login-into-google-account-through-new-ajax-login-form/45953576#45953576) as well.