# Gmail Automatic Login via C# (Selenium) in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013

I can't fill the password in the password field. I am not sure where am I wrong. The current code that I am using is filling the password in the same field with the email address. 
I am using the following code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
 namespace Cube
 {
  [TestClass]
  public class Setup
  {
    static IWebDriver driverGC;

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
    {
        driverGC = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestChromeDriver()
    {
        driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
        driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("gb_70")).Click();
        driverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#identifierId.whsOnd.zHQkBf")).SendKeys("mail@gmail.com");
        driverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#identifierId.whsOnd.zHQkBf")).Click();
        driverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".whsOnd.zHQkBf")).SendKeys("password123");
        driverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".whsOnd.zHQkBf")).Click();
        driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
    }
}
      }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium test scripts to login into google account through new ajax login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953043/selenium-test-scripts-to-login-into-google-account-through-new-ajax-login-form)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code to detect the WebElements for login in Gmail, to avoid timing issues you have to add some (Explicit) waiting before calling the method.

```
public static void LoginGmail (IWebDriver driver, string email, string password )
    {          
        var loginBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email"));
        loginBox.SendKeys(email);

        var nextBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Id("next"));
        nextBtn.Click();

        var pwBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Passwd"));
        pwBox.SendKeys(password);

        var signinBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Id("signIn"));
        signinBtn.Click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this (working code):

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects;

public class GoogleLoginPage : BasePageObject
    {
        public GoogleLoginPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver) { }

        const string _url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin";

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "identifierId")]
        IWebElement GoogleInput { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[id='identifierNext']")]
        IWebElement GoogleButton { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[name='password']")]
        IWebElement GooglePassInput { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[id='passwordNext']")]
        IWebElement GooglePassButton { get; set; }

        public void LoginAccountGoogleSitePage()
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_url);
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            wait.Until(d => GoogleLoginInput.Displayed);
            GoogleInput.SendKeys("mail@gmail.com");
            GoogleButton.Click();
            GooglePassInput.SendKeys("password123");
            GooglePassButton.Click();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is `BasePageObject` and `GoogleLoginInput` here?

Answer (score 0):

So, I am using the code below for another site. You can use it as an example and use some parts in your work.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace Auto_Login_Bot
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IWebDriver driverGC = new ChromeDriver();

            const string _url = "site-name";

            const string usr = "";
            const string pass = "";

            driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl(_url);
            IWebElement Login = driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("authorization-email-input"));
            IWebElement Password = driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("authorization-password-input"));
            IWebElement LoginButton = driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("authorization-submit-button"));
            Login.SendKeys(usr);
            Password.SendKeys(pass);
            LoginButton.Click();
        }
    }
}
```