# Can not type password in google Sign In using selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-signin

Can not type password in google Sign In using selenium

```java
public class FirtsTest extends WebDriverSettings {

    @Test
    public void  firstTest() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com.ua/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement SignInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("gb_70"));
        SignInButton.click();
        WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
        Login.clear();
        Login.sendKeys("angelslayer1995");
        WebElement NextButton = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext"));
        NextButton.click();
        WebElement PasswordInput = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']"));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(PasswordInput));
        PasswordInput.clear();
        PasswordInput.sendKeys("02091995");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Can not type password"*? Did you get an exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium test scripts to login into google account through new ajax login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953043/selenium-test-scripts-to-login-into-google-account-through-new-ajax-login-form)

Answer (score 0):

Google Scrambles every locators for preventing automatic inputs using scripts. You shouldn't try to automate signing in, your IP will be blacklisted immediately.